# User Managed Templating for Custom Message in Laravel

Tags: php, security, laravel, laravel-blade, templating

I am in the process of creating a WebApp in Laravel where the registered business users will be able to send out automated emails to their customers with the help of all the data stored in the app. The App is a sort of CRM. But for creating the custom email, I want to give the customer the ability to crated their own text and a bit of logic.

Currently , I have set it up so only the predefined variables can be used along with some HTML. I parse the markup to generate the email. As defined below.

- Use predefined variables. Ex. [{cFullName}] for the Customer's full name.

The problem I face is if the user wants to add some sort of logic, say example :

- Loop thru and print all the OrderItems
- If the Order shipping Vendor is FedEx then add the Message saying Tracking link will be live after 8PM.

  What I currently have used Blade that comes by default in Laravel. As it will give me the ability to give a lot more flexibility to the users.

It works perfectly fine in the Dev environment and solves the purpose but there is the issue.

The only issue is , this would come with its own set of security issue, as I try to store multiple Blade templates each user in the DB and compile it at run time when the send email event it triggered.

Would appreciate if someone can give me an idea on a way to make user added Blade more restrictive and secure or a completely different option. As letting users add logic in the application is a tough one to achieve securely.

Comment: A comment would be appreciated for the Down Vote. Thanks. As it is a Programming related question, fair enough its on the way to achieve the logic in a more secure manner but by writing code.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Blade is designed to be used by developer so avoid using Blade for user content. As an alternative, you can create your own predefined sets of syntax available to user that will be replaced by actual command. This may put some limitation but again we do not like funny business.